# Chang & Keisler on Abelian Groups

Tags: model-theory

“Suppose *p* is prime. The theory of *Abelian groups with all elements of order p* has the extra axiom

(5) $px = 0$
“

I’m just trying to make sense of why this would even be the case. If we have an Abelian group with all elements of infinite order then how does infinite cardinality multiplied by a given *x* ever end up equaling *0*...?

Comment: Infinite order is not a first order sentence. It is a first order schema.

Comment: @AsafKaragila how is an order of an element anything other than infinite...? I’m sure this is basic but I’m just not “seeing” it

Comment: @mizejonathan17 Are you familiar with any finite abelian groups? (E.g. integers mod $2$?)

Comment: (Also, I think there's a typo in your question: I suspect the extra axiom should be "$px=0$" instead.)

Comment: What is the order of $1$ in $\Bbb{Z/2Z}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am not

Comment: Why are you reading about the model theory of abelian groups if you are not familiar with some of the basic properties of them?

Comment: @AsafKaragila fair enough. I'm working from a solely logic-centered background, but find model theory beautiful

Comment: @mizejonathan17 The model theory of a class of structures - like abelian groups - builds on the existing theory of those structures. It is indeed beautiful but it rarely makes sense in a vacuum.

Comment: @NoahSchweber would you say it would be best to skim such parts dealing with abstract algebra and come back to them later or to brush up now and continue w Chang & Keisler? thanks

Comment: @mizejonathan17 I would say the latter. A big part of the motivation for model theory comes from abstract algebra and its various successes, so I'd recommend a decent background in abstract algebra before tackling model theory.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that $\equiv$ is equality in Chang & Keisler, not the biconditional.

Comment: Incidentally, one annoying thing I've seen repeatedly is abelian groups being introduced as generalizations of ($\mathbb{Z},+$). This definitely makes finite abelian groups seem weirder than they should, which might be the case here. The right way to introduce abelian groups in my opinion is by starting with modular arithmetic(s) as the motivating example; certainly the idea that the integers form the "ideal abelian group" is not a useful one.

Comment: There has been a lot of good discussion around this question already. But I actually don't understand your question. "I'm just trying to make sense of why this would even be the case" - there's no *why* in axioms. By definition, "all elements have order p" means $\forall x\, px = 0$. So if we add this axiom to the axioms for abelian groups, we have axiomatized the abelian groups in which all elements have order $p$. "If we have an Abelian group with all elements of infinite order..." Where does infinite order come up? The quote from C&K begins "Suppose $p$ is prime". So $p\neq \infty$...

Comment: Anyway, I'll second Noah's comment that your question seems really to be a question about abelian groups, not about model theory. It's not impossible to learn model theory "from scratch" but it's certainly harder. If you haven't studied basic abstract algebra, you will be confused every time you meet an algebraic example - and many of the examples and intuitions/motivations in model theory come from algebra.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of abelian groups where *every* element has finite order. For example, any finite abelian group has this property, and there are lots of those. The trivial group - the unique (up to isomorphism) group with a single element - is the simplest example, but there are plenty of others. You're probably familiar with [the integers modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Examples) (for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>1$) from basic number theory or combinatorics; this forms a group (called "$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$") under addition modulo $n$, and every element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has order dividing $n$. In particular, if $n$ is prime then every (non-identity) element has order $n$.

There are even *infinite* abelian groups where every element has finite order! Most simply, take any infinite [direct power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) *(= direct product where all the factors are the same)* of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some fixed $n$. When $n$ is prime, we get an infinite abelian group where every non-identity element has order $n$.

A bit more interestingly, any infinite [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups) of finite abelian groups has this property, although it may exhibit elements of wildly different finite orders. In particular, the group $$\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N},n>1}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$ has every element of finite order and elements of every finite order.

---

I can't resist ending with my personal favorite example: the group $$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.$$ Intuitively, elements of this group are rational numbers in $[0,1)$, and addition is given by "wrapping around" just like in modular arithmetic (so e.g. ${1\over 2}+{2\over 3}={7\over 6}-1={1\over 6}$ in this group).

$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has a number of cute properties. It's an infinite abelian group where every element has finite order (think about $q\cdot {p\over q}$), but there are elements of every finite order (think about ${1\over n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Additionally, all its finitely-generated subgroups are generated by a single element (think about how $\langle {1\over 2},{1\over 3}\rangle=\langle{1\over 6}\rangle$) but the whole group is not finitely generated, and in particular this illustrates the limits of [the classification theorem for *finitely generated* abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification). And more subtly, while it makes perfect sense as a group there's no way to [define a good notion of multiplication on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). It's a counterexample to many reasonable-sounding conjectures about abelian groups.